# Customizing WPF Expander; Make only icon clickable not whole header

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, expander

I want an `Expander` that only expands/collapse it's content when the user clicks on the header icon. (Instead of the whole header being clickable.)

Do I have to redefine the control `Template` to do this? How would it look like?
Where can I find the standard templates/styles for controls?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396153/preventing-a-wpf-expander-from-expanding-when-header-is-clicked.  You should be able to find your solution there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a solution to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396153/preventing-a-wpf-expander-from-expanding-when-header-is-clicked) (same link as in the comment from Ben).

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a much simpler XAML solution than modifying templates. Simply DON'T use the Expander's header property in this case. Instead, cover the expander with your own styled TextBlock.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeader" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="21,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9,3,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Expander>
        <TextBlock Text="I am some content. I have disowned my default header." Margin="10,5" />
    </Expander>
    <TextBlock Text="I'm filling in for the default header. You'll like me better anyway."
               Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ExpanderHeader}"/>
</Grid>
```