# How do I swallow the dropdown behavior inside an Expander.Header?

Tags: wpf, expander, routed-events

I would like to prevent an Expander from expanding/collapsing when users click inside the header area. This is basically the same question as [Q 1396153](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396153), but I'd appreciate a more favorable answer :)

Is there a non-invasive way to do this? I am not sure exactly how to attach behavior to the Expander.Header content to prevent mouseclicks. I'm willing to float in content outside the expander itself via a fixed grid layout, but I'm not keen on the solution. Ideas?

XamlPad sample XAML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Expander>
    <Expander.Header><TextBlock>
        When I click this text, 
        I don't want to trigger expansion/collapse! Only when I click the 
        expander button do I want to trigger an expand/collapse!
    </TextBlock></Expander.Header>

    <Grid Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100" >
    </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop mouse clicks on the text box from being handled by your application.

XAML:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"> 
            When I click this text,  
            I don't want to trigger expansion/collapse! Only when I click the  
            expander button do I want to trigger an expand/collapse!
                    </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
    <Grid Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100" >
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried it yet, but am optimistic it will solve the problem

Comment: Please note that: This solution does not obey the strict MVVM approach

Comment: No code behind (which i guess you mean with strict MVVM approach) can be achieved by moving the code to suppress the mouse down event to an attached behavior or subclassing the Expander class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an abomination, but, I've moved the content out of the Expander.Header and done some Grid/fixed layout/Panel.ZIndex trickery to make it appear that the content is in the Expander.Header...but it's not. This works, but it's horrible.